# Nginx+bottle+uwsgi Server returning 404 on every request

Tags: python, nginx, amazon-ec2, uwsgi, bottle

I have setup an Nginx server with following configuration:

```
server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.notesapi.socket;
                uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME /home/ubuntu/notesAPI/env;
                uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHIDIR /home/ubuntu/notesAPI/src;
                uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT Notes;
        }

}
```

I have setup a bottle app with initial following initial script:

```
import sys from settings.constants import PROJECT_ROOT print PROJECT_ROOT sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_ROOT)

import bottle from bottle import Bottle, debug from settings import routes

Notes = Bottle() routes.set(Notes)

debug(True)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Notes.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, reloader=True)
else:
    application = bottle.default_app()
```

When I send a GET request to the server I get a 404 even though the routes are perfectly set.

Here is the `uwsgi.log`:

> [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini
>
> [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/uwsgi.ini
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - *** Starting uWSGI 1.0.3-debian (64bit) on [Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013] ***
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 17 July 2012 02:26:54
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - current working directory: /
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - writing pidfile to /run/uwsgi/app/uwsgi/pid
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - setgid() to 33
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - setuid() to 33
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - your memory page size is 4096 bytes
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /run/uwsgi/app/uwsgi/socket fd 5
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - uwsgi socket 1 bound to UNIX address /tmp/uwsgi.notesapi.socket fd 6
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:25:23)  [GCC 4.6.3]
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - Set PythonHome to /home/ubuntu/notesAPI/env
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1f27e60
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - *** Operational MODE: preforking ***
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - added /home/ubuntu/notesAPI/src/ to pythonpath.
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 25575)
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 25583, cores: 1)
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:47:26 2013 - spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 25584, cores: 1)
>
> /home/ubuntu/notesAPI/src
>
> Fri Jun 21 04:55:28 2013 - WSGI application 0 (mountpoint='') ready on interpreter 0x1f27e60 pid: 25583 (default app) [pid: 25583|app: 0|req: 1/1] 117.196.135.124 () {44 vars in 686 bytes} [Fri Jun 21 04:55:28 2013] GET / => generated 723 bytes in 188 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 87 bytes (1 switches on core 0)

I am pretty new to uwsgi and nginx. I can't seem to figure out the problem.

Comment: "even though the routes are perfectly set" -- how do you know?

Comment: I've tried t locally. And works fine there.

Comment: "Locally" in what sense? Sorry, I don't get what you mean. Maybe if you show us your route definitions in the question, it'll be clearer?

Comment: Sorry. By locally I meant that I have setup a virtualenv and setup the bottle server in my machine. And it runs smoothly. But there I make use of the uwsgi server that is present in Bottle. And also there is no nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that NGINX and UWSGI are working properly? Lot's of things could be wrong, I recommend you to follow this guide: https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

It's a step by step to setup NGINX and UWSGI with Django but I'm pretty sure you can apply it to any other web app than Django.

Comment: Thanks a lot dablak. I havent gone through the page yet. I am caught up in somethings for some days. Will go through it soon.

Comment: Got a better understanding of how things work. Thanks a lot dablak.
It helped escalate error from 404 to 502

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Are you saying that now you get a 502 error?